# Menu bar missing on some programs

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, xfce, thunderbird

I'm running XFCE on Ubuntu 16.04.5. Two days ago the menu bar disappeared randomly in LibreOffice programs only, still worked in other programs like FileZilla, Thunar, Thunderbird, etc. But in LibreOffice programs Writer, Calc, and others, menu bar is completely gone:

[image]

I chocked it up to something in LO, so I left it until I had a chance to fix.

This morning I start up the computer and now Thunderbird is missing it's menu bar, just gone. It was there yesterday, but today gone. Also, my extension buttons are gone from the toolbar as well, only default buttons are there.

[image]

But Menu Bar is selected as there in the right click menu on the toolbar.

FileZilla and Thunar still have their menu bars. So do other programs. Starting up GIMP it still has it's menu:

[image]

I'm figuring something in GTK or another subsystem has been corrupted, but I don't know what controls those items, so I'm not sure where to begin.

I've tried a couple things, none of which have fixed it:

```
compiz --replace
```

Just replaces everything with a blue bar, still no menu bar.

```
xfwm4 --replace
```

No change at all.

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt unity-gtk3-module unity-gtk2-module
```

Same, no change.

**EDIT**

If I remove `libreoffice-gtk` and start LO it comes up with pre-GTK menu:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk
```

But once I add it back it goes away again. Is this a problem with GTK and how would I fix that in general?

**EDIT**

Re-Installing thunderbird does not fix the problem with thunderbird. I've also tried re-installing `xubuntu-desktop` with no avail.

Comment: Why don't you click the image icon above the question box area to include your image more conveniently (for you and the people who view your question)?

Answer (score 2):

For Thunderbird, right-click at the top of the screen (where the menubar would be) and check “Menu Bar”.

The answer for LibreOffice seems to be disabling OpenGL rendering, go to Tools > Options > View > uncheck “Use OpenGL for all rendering”. It is probably [this bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107764)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cannot get to the menu to go to tools. Also, thunderbird already has that Menu Bar checked. Not remotely the correct answer.

Comment: I was able to get to the options by adding it to my toolbar.   1.  Right click anywhere on the toolbar and select "Customize toolbar..."   2.  Scroll down in the "Available Commands" to find "Option" and add it to the existing toolbar.  3.  Close the customize dialog.  4. Click on the new "Options" toolbar button

Comment: In when in the "LibreOffice" -> "View" options I found a checkbox for "Use hardware acceleration" but not one specifically about OpenGL.   Checking and unchecking the hardware acceleration does not show or hide the menu toolbar.

Comment: I also found I could add a "Menubar" button to my toolbar.   However, the menu bar doesn't show up whether or not the menu bar button on the toolbar is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Press the `alt` button for menubar.